Faster method to check if a string is found inside Word Files in a directory and subdirectories
I need to check if a string is found inside a Word File in a directory and subdirectories.
I have tried to use Advanced Search of MS Windows 10, to search inside file contents. The benefits of this approach that Windows system is using internal API to search for the required string without opening any files.
But, it has many disadvantages, especially it takes a very long time to finish, besides it searches inside all file types.
I have used the below code, it works, but it is also slow, and I need to get the full Path of the file containing the required string.
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub Check_if_a_String_found_inside_WordFiles_in_a_Directory()

    Const searchText As String = "Test String"           'Set the search text
    Const myFolder As String = "C:\Your\Folder\Path\"    'path of the folder where Word files are located
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim wordApp As Object, wordDoc As Object, myFile As String, i As Long
    
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")   'Initialize Word application
    wordApp.Visible = False                          'Set to True if you want to see Word
    
    myFile = Dir(myFolder & "*.doc*")         'Loop through each file in the folder
    
    i = 1
    
    Do While myFile <> ""
        
        Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(myFolder & myFile)   'Open the Word file
        
        With wordDoc.Content.Find           'Search for the text
            .Text = searchText
            If .Execute Then
                ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = myFile:  i = i + 1
            End If
        End With
        
        wordDoc.Close False        'Close the Word file
        
        myFile = Dir               'Get the next file in the folder
    Loop
    
    wordApp.Quit              'Close Word application
    
    ' Cleanup
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
    Set wordApp = Nothing
End Sub


I think using Window's own search tool is going to be the quickest. You mention a 'all file types' issue, but you should be able to combine a 'contents' search with a filetype search - e.g. contents:"look_for_this" *.docx
